# Deleting text in a file with "sed" isn't working as expected

Tags: linux, sh

I am currently working on a little script for the "nslookup"-command and in my testing I encountered a problem I don't understand. In my script a .txt file is automatically created and the user can input some text to it if he wishes to. He can also delete specific lines in the document. I tried writing it with "sed" but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Here the menu from the terminal output:

```
Domains:
1) new_domain
2) domain
3) Create new Domain
4) Delete a Domain
5) Quit
Input>
```

The first two numbers also representing the line of each text.
The code for deleting a domain is the following:

```
filename=domains.txt
old_filename=domains_backup.txt
read -p "Which domain-number shall be deleted?: " num_input
mv $filename $old_filename
sed "/$num_input/d" < $old_filename > $filename
rm $old_filename
```

But when executing that script and the user wants to delete line 2 (domain) the text-file remains the same and is not updated.
When I try the same only using the terminal everything works fine.
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It is not clear what your menu output has to do with the shell commands you show in the question. What do you mean with "When I try the same only using the terminal"? Are you manually executing the commands shown in the question? Please show the contents of the file `domains.txt`

Comment: Yes I manually execute the same commands in the terminal. And what's inside of the `domains.txt` I already have written: It's the first two lines presented: `new_domain` and `domain`. Also: the menu has something to do with the code under it since the menu is always updating after each executed option

Comment: Without your answer it is unclear what "The first two numbers also representing the line of each text." means. Your question is a bit confusing. It would be much clearer if you would (also) show the contents of `domains.txt` and explain that your script will add the numbers and some additional lines to create the menu. But the menu is not really relevant for your problem. It is important to know how exactly your file contents looks like, i.e. that it contains the 1st line `new_domain` and the 2nd line `domain` without the numbers, and that the entered number denotes the line number to delete.

Comment: Thank you I'll keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a line by its line number you will want to use `$num_input d` rather than `/$num_input/d` : the second one matches lines that contain `$num_input`.

As a side note, if you use GNU `sed` you could let it handle the backup :

```
sed -i.backup "$num_input d" domains.txt
```

This would create a copy of the untouched `domains.txt` as `domains.txt.backup` (or whatever suffix you specify after `-i`) and update the `domains.txt` file.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked with only writing `"$num_input d"`